# Demasiados argumentos para el método de llamada. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

quería saber si podéis ayudarme con dos problemas que tengo, el primero de ellos es al invocar un método dentro de otro. El error que me da es  que hay demasiados argumentos para el método de llamada. (hay flechas donde me da error) y otro error es que cuando quiero abrir un fichero con el nombre filename, me dice que no está definido. Lo que quiero hacer es que filename llame al método exterior para que me devuelva el nombre y que con ese nombre pueda abrirlo como un fichero.

```
def nombre_archivo(self, mode, sock, server):

    ....
    print('Por favor introduzca el nombre del archivo.\n')
    filename = str(input("TFTP@UDP > "))
    filename = filename.encode('ascii')

    ....
    return filename

def metodo_2(self, sock, numBlock, buffer, data, sigBlock, contDup, dup, fin, maxblckside, mode, server):

    while True:
        sigBlock = 0
   -- > filename = self.nombre_archivo(self, mode, sock, server)
        buffer = sock.recvfrom(maxblckside)
        opcode = struct.unpack("!H", buffer[:2])
        if opcode == 3:
            numBlock = struct.unpack("!H", buffer[2:4])
            data = struct.unpack("!HH", buffer[4:])
            for sigBlock in numBlock:
                if sigBlock != numBlock :
          -->       f = open (filemane, 'r')
                    for linea in f:
                        f.write(data)
                    f.close()
                   .........
        return fin
```

Comment: Hola Jorge. **La instancia de la clase (`self`) se pasa de forma automática a un método de instancia como primer argumento**, En `self.nombre_archivo(self, mode, sock, server)` debe ser `self.nombre_archivo(mode, sock, server)`, es decir te sobra `self` como primer argumento.

Comment: El otro error es un typo, no es `f = open (filemane, 'r')` debe ser `f = open (filename, 'r')`. tienes file**m**a**n**e.  Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @FJSevilla , lo del filename de verdad que era una tontería pero no lo veía. gracias. Otra duda que tengo, ¿si una variable te la señala como que no la usas, a la hora de ejecutar el código habría algún problema?

Comment: No hay ningún problema, eso es el analizador de código del IDE que informa que estás declarando y asignando un valor a una variable que luego no usas nunca, por lo que ocupas recursos de forma innecesaria, aparte de "ensuciar" el código. Pero un error como tal no es y el programa se va a ejecutar perfectamente, aunque deberías eliminarla si de verdad no se usa para nada.

Comment: @FJSevilla En una línea del codigo pongo un for linea in f: me sale ese error en linea, si que la utilizo para recorrer un fichero.

Comment: ¿Pero usas la variable `linea` dentro del `for`? Porque si no lo haces deberías hacer `for _ in f:` En tu código haces `f.write(data)` en el `for`, por lo que no usas linea para nada, de todas formas veo esta línea de código un poco extraña... Por cada linea del archivo escribes `data` al final del mismo... Aparte de esto, `f` lo abres en modo lectura, no puedes usar `f.write`...

Comment: @FJSevilla no, no la uso, probaré con lo que me has puesto. Sé que es un poco extraño, es la primera vez que programo en python. Gracias